# Show div if option value matching - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a div if the value of option is matching, not able to show, please help!

**NOTE:** Cannot use ID or class of the div since the html is generated dynamically and it may get changed, so targeted is option value

**Here is the code :**

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($('option').val() == 'Clear my checklist') {
    $('.showcontent').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___jqName" style="position: relative;" size="1" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-label="Drop-down List" id="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___widget">
    <option id="emptyValue" role="option" value="Options" style="">Options</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Print my checklist">Print my checklist</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Email my checklist">Email my checklist</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Clear my checklist">Clear my checklist</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Sign out of my checklist">Sign out of my checklist</option>
</select>
<div class="showcontent" style="display:none;">Show content if value matching</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$(this).val()` to use the value of the selected option:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Clear my checklist') {
    $('.showcontent').show();
  } else {
    $('.showcontent').hide();
  }
});
```

The `$('option').val()` it trying to look for the "option" element and get the value of that, and that would not work.

**Demo**

```js
$('select').change(function() {
console.log($('option').val())
  if ($(this).val() == 'Clear my checklist') {
    $('.showcontent').show();
  } else {
    $('.showcontent').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___jqName" style="position: relative;" size="1" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-label="Drop-down List" id="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___widget">
        <option id="emptyValue" role="option" value="Options" style="">Options</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Print my checklist">Print my checklist</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Email my checklist">Email my checklist</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Clear my checklist">Clear my checklist</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Sign out of my checklist">Sign out of my checklist</option>
    </select>
<div class="showcontent" style="display:none;">Show content if value matching</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, actually is it possible to use tag name instead `this` as where I am adding this event..where change fucntion is somehow generated dynamically so `this` not working in my case

Comment: @SanjeevKumar that doesn't make sense as `this` will relate to the `select` which fired the event. The event handler itself is identical to what you already had.

Comment: actually change event is fired from API, and I do not have control over that, only the inner code can be edit, what are other way..?

Comment: @SanjeevKumar `$('select:focus > option:selected').val()` would do it BUT that just sounds like a XY problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for let me know about stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> `$('option').val()` will always return the value of the first option whatever you're selecting.

You need to get the selected value using `$(this).val()` instead, like:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Clear my checklist') {
        $('.showcontent').show(); 
    } 
});
```

Code:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('.showcontent').hide();
  if ($(this).val() == 'Clear my checklist') {
    $('.showcontent').show();
  }

  console.log($('option').val() + ' ---- ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___jqName" style="position: relative;" size="1" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-label="Drop-down List" id="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___widget">
    <option id="emptyValue" role="option" value="Options" style="">Options</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Print my checklist">Print my checklist</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Email my checklist">Email my checklist</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Clear my checklist">Clear my checklist</option>
    <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Sign out of my checklist">Sign out of my checklist</option>
</select>
<div class="showcontent" style="display:none;">Show content if value matching</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this.value.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  if (this.value == 'Clear my checklist') {
    $('.showcontent').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___jqName" style="position: relative;" size="1" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-label="Drop-down List" id="guideContainer-rootPanel-checklist-guidedropdownlist___widget">
        <option id="emptyValue" role="option" value="Options" style="">Options</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Print my checklist">Print my checklist</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Email my checklist">Email my checklist</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Clear my checklist">Clear my checklist</option>
        <option role="option" data-user-option="" value="Sign out of my checklist">Sign out of my checklist</option>
    </select>
<div class="showcontent" style="display:none;">Show content if value matching</div>
```

Comment: You have literally copied the above 2 answers. Thats not how so works

Comment: @Tomm, I didn't copy the things. I am writing my answers and checking it. Meanwhile, they have posted it... when my answer is posted. I got that someone already replied on this.

Comment: @Tomm Mittal is right, actually same thing happened with me as well and people think that, same answer is copied. Actually this answer could be the suggestion in the comment.

Comment: @NitinDhomse that answer can not have taken 6 minutes, and you look at answers before you answer the question right

Comment: @Tomm, Actually your are right there is 5-6 min difference in the both answers, but he might be busy with something else, anyways no problem.

Comment: @Tomm, it is not like when we start answering the question and post in minutes...  at the same time, we might involve in some other work for a while. So to post answer may take time. I also believe that there is no meaning to post the same answer again. We are here to help others...